# How can I make browser remember form values for autocomplete on ajax submit?

Tags: html, forms, autocomplete

I have created a form, which on submit does a ajax call for the submission. It is not a standard form submit. How can I make browser remember form data(not just username and password) for autocomplete? I have tried submitting the form to hidden iframe but it is only working for chrome. Is there a solution or workaround which can work on all the browser.

Comment: autocomplete function is an automatic browser feature (it saves the last words that you type).
You can disable autocompletation
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530/how-do-you-disable-browser-autocomplete-on-web-form-field-input-tag?rq=1

Comment: Have you had the chance to find a solution? I can't seem to find anything about *forcing* persistence while handling the form with Javascript.

Answer (score 5):

I finally found the solution to this.

Basically the browser store the input value when the `submit` event is triggered on the form.

All you need to do is then prevent the page reload by calling the `event.preventDefault()` function and handle the rest with Javascript.

Here's a basic example : https://codesandbox.io/s/phnsn

```
<form name="jsForm">
    <input type="text" name="search" autocomplete="search" />
    <button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>

<script>
    document.jsForm.addEventListener("submit", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        // Handle Ajax call here
    });
</script>
```

Keep in mind that if you added a click event on the submit button, you still need to programmatically trigger the `submit` event. So it's best to use a button with submit type.